# Unable to start Deployd (MongoDB failed to start)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployd

I am new to Deployd, and am trying to open the dashboard. I started by creating a basic `hello-world` project folder:

```
$ cd hello-world
```

...then ran the following to view the dashboard:

```
$ dpd-d
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
vaibhav@vaibhav:/hello-world$ dpd -d
   starting deployd v0.8.4...
   Failed to start MongoDB (Make sure 'mongod' are in your $PATH or use dpd    --mongod option. Ref: http://docs.deployd.com/docs/basics/cli.html)
bye

fs.js:432
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied './.dpd/pids/mongod'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:971:15)
    at process.kill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/deployd/lib/util/mongod.js:52:8)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at process.exit (node.js:707:17)
    at fn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/deployd/bin/dpd:261:5)
    at stop (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/deployd/bin/dpd:270:5)
    at startup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/deployd/bin/dpd:162:16)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/deployd/lib/util/mongod.js:62:5)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:795:12)
`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any help in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: try this:  `sudo chown $(whoami)  ~/.dpd `

Answer (score 0):

To check if mongodb is properly installed:

If you are in iOS or Linux you can try:

```
sudo dpd
```

If you are in Windows try opening a command window with "Run as Administrator" and try:

```
dpd
```

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure you have mongodb installed and you can call it from commandline:
On Unix,

```
which mongod
```

On Windows,

```
where mongod
```

Once you're sure that's available, ensure you have read-write access to your **deployed** project directory, sub-directories and files:
On Unix,

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 /path/to/deployd/project/directory
```

I don't think this problem applies to Windows OS.

After that, try to start your project dashboard again.

```
dpd dashboard
```